# 'Click' action conflict with `submit` action

Tags: javascript

So, I have the following setup with a `Submit` button that saves any changes.

```
   <div class="mysite-body">

    <?php do_action('mysite_pre_form_message'); ?>

    <form action="" method="post" data-action="<?php echo $template; ?>">

        <input type="hidden" name="user_id-<?php echo $i; ?>" id="user_id-<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />

        <?php 
        if (!isset($user_id)) $user_id = 0;
        $hook_args = array_merge($args, array('user_id' => $user_id, 'unique_id' => $i));
        do_action('mysite_before_fields', $hook_args);
        ?>

        <?php foreach( mysite_fields_group_by_template( $template, $args["{$template}_group"] ) as $key => $array ) { ?>

            <?php  if ($array) echo mysite_edit_field( $key, $array, $i, $args, $user_id ) ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php 
        if (!isset($user_id)) $user_id = 0;
        $hook_args = array_merge($args, array('user_id' => $user_id, 'unique_id' => $i));
        do_action('mysite_after_fields', $hook_args);
        ?>

        <?php 
        if (!isset($user_id)) $user_id = 0;
        $hook_args = array_merge($args, array('user_id' => $user_id, 'unique_id' => $i));
        do_action('mysite_before_form_submit', $hook_args);
        ?>

        <?php if ( mysite_can_delete_user($user_id) || $mysite->request_verification($user_id) || isset( $args["{$template}_button_primary"] ) || isset( $args["{$template}_button_secondary"] ) ) { ?>
        <div class="mysite-field mysite-submit mysite-column" id="A">

            <?php if (isset($args["{$template}_button_primary"]) ) { ?>
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $args["{$template}_button_primary"]; ?>" class="mysite-button" />
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if (isset( $args["{$template}_button_mysite"] )) { ?>
            <input type="button" value="<?php echo $args["{$template}_button_secondary"]; ?>" class="mysite-button secondary" data-template="<?php echo $args["{$template}_button_action"]; ?>" />
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( $mysite->request_verification($user_id) ) { ?>
            <input type="button" value="<?php _e('Request Verification','mysite'); ?>" class="popup-request_verify mysite-button secondary" data-up_username="<?php echo $mysite->id_to_member($user_id); ?>" />
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( mysite_can_delete_user($user_id) ) { ?>
            <input type="button" value="<?php _e('Delete Profile','mysite'); ?>" class="mysite-button red" data-template="delete" data-up_username="<?php echo $mysite->id_to_member($user_id); ?>" />
            <?php } ?>

            <img src="<?php echo $mysite->skin_url(); ?>loading.gif" alt="" class="mysite-loading" />
            <div class="mysite-clear"></div>

        </div>
        <?php } ?>

    </form>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Then following javascript:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[

jQuery("#A").click(function(){   
jQuery("#B").trigger('click');    
return false;       }); 


// ]]></script>
```

And `id="B"` is on a header as a simple anchor button:

```
 <div class="startskip"><a id="B" href="http://mysite/start/item">Skip</a></div>
```

What I want to achieve is that when a `submit` button is clicked, then the `skip` button is also triggered and the user will be redirected to the next page.
Of course, I am going to put `setTimeout`so there is enough time to save instead of instant redirect.

However, the `submit` button becomes not-responsive when I add the javascript.
So, it seems that there is a javascript conflict between the `click` function and `submit` function. (Without the javascript, the `submit` button works).

By looking the code, could you guys figure out what the problem is and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the submit button inside a `form` element?

Comment: I just updated my code, and yes it is in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read an article on this previously which explains why it doesn't work - but have lost the link, I'll see if I can find it an update this post tomorrow. But the summary would be to say that the jQuery trigger click method triggers the event handler for the element, it does not trigger the browsers default behaviour i.e. following a link.

You have two choices, if you must use jQuery, then you can use this:

```
window.location = $('#B').attr('href');
```

Another option is to use pure JS:

```
document.getElementById("a_link").click();
```

In this case, I would go for the second option since I think it is more clear and readable - but that's subjective!

Comment: Also, see ekuusela's comment below - they are right that to make the submit button work you should remove the return false and that using AJAX is almost certainly neater in this case that setting a time out too.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for the information. I have never used `document.getElementById`. Where do I place it and how do I use it? Thanks Sam

Comment: Get element by id is the exact same as saying $('#b') but it's pure JavaScript no jquery.  I would recommend you take a tutorial in JavaScript so you understand the fundamentals...  As for how to use it:  if you replace the first line of your function with document.getElementById('B').click();  also read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Answer (score 0):

The `return false` inside the click handler cancels the original click and that is why the form doesn't get submitted.

I don't think it's possible to run any script after the form submission though. You could try submitting the form with ajax and on success do the redirect.

Comment: You are right. Even with `return false` removed, the script does not run after the form submission. I am going to try Sam's method and see if I can make it work! =) Thanks ekuusela!